# How can I sum user input numbers whilst in a loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to get the sum of numbers that a user inputs in a loop, but I can't get it to include the first number input - here's what I have so far

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
total = 0
while number != -1:
 number = int(input("Enter another number"))
 total += number
else:
  print(total)
```

Probably something easy I'm missing but I'm stumped ( i am a beginner as you can tell)

I have tried changing the name of the first variable number but I end up in a constant loop even when number = -1

Comment: You need to move the line: `total += number` up one place. That way you will include the first number and not include the `-1` entered to break the loop.

Comment: What if you just initialize total = number instead of zero?

Answer (score 0):

```
number = int(input("Enter a number"))
total = 0
while number != -1:
    total += number
    number = int(input("Enter another number"))
else:
    print(total)
```

Just move the summation one line above.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much !! of course it was that easy